# How to make a smooth highly contrasted image from a Blur, without affecting the sides?

Tags: image-processing

I'm generating a random texture using the code above, by blurring random tiles:

```
randomTiles = 
  Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomInteger[{1, 2}]}, {n, 1, 
    1500}];

Sharpen[Blur[ListDensityPlot[
   randomTiles,
   ColorFunction -> "IslandColors",
   InterpolationOrder -> 0,
   Frame -> False,
   ImageSize -> {500, 500}
   ], 10], 2]
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

Currently, the `Blur` is also changing the sides of the picture, and the `Sharpen` isn't doing what I need.  So here's what I would like to achieve:

1. Transforming the image without any blur or other effects to the sides, which need to stay sharp.  Cropping the picture should be avoided, if possible.
2. Transforming the blurred texture to a very sharpened and contrasting texture, with smooth edges everywhere, so I get two color regions only without any gradient.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try using `GaussianFilter` instead of `Blur` and modifying the `Padding` option instead.

Comment: @CarlLange, how do you use Padding in this code?  Can you give a specific example as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PlotRangePadding` to deal with edges, `Binarize` to unblur, and then `Colorize` to get your colors back

```
Colorize[Binarize[
  Blur[ListDensityPlot[randomTiles, ColorFunction -> "IslandColors", 
    InterpolationOrder -> 0, Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
    ImageSize -> {500, 500}], 10], .6 ], 
    ColorRules -> {0 -> Orange, 1 -> Green}]
```

[image: Output Sample]

Comment: Without your Colorize command, how would you make the black and white edges smooth, without jaggies?

Comment: Changed ImagePadding-> 0 to PlotRangePadding->0 fixes boarders. Fixed in answer above.

Comment: The PlotRangePadding option is great!  Thanks!